# Triangle side-length problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

my problem is the following.

> A triangle ABC is given. P is a point on $\overline{AB}$. $k_1, k_2, k$ are the radii of the in-circles of APC, BPC, ABC. $s_1, s_2, s$ are radii of the ex-circles of these triangles which are lying at the angle ACB.
>
> Show that \begin{equation}
> \frac{k_1}{s_1} \cdot \frac{k_2}{s_2} = \frac{k}{s}
> \end{equation}

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are the excircles of the triangles. I suppose you mean the ones tangent to the line $AB$, correct?

Comment: @gebruiker An excircle of a triangle is a circle which is tangent to 1 line of the triangle from outside. In this case the excircles are tangent to for example CP, or CA. ;)